# whats the come back in this CPU scheduling algorithms task?

Tags: c, operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture, scheduling

Consider the following set of processes:

Once each process is done processing its “Burst Time”, it goes to the waiting queue, then “Comes back” to the ready queue after the time shown.

You are required to simulate the CPU schedule for a period of 200 time units.

For each of the following scheduling algorithms, your program must show the Gantt chart, average waiting time, and average turnaround time.

```
1- First Come First Served.
2- Shortest Job First.
3- Shortest Remaining Time First.
4- Round Robin, with q = 5
5- Preemptive Priority Scheduling, with aging; where priority is decremented by 
1 if the process remains in the ready queue for 5 time units.
6- Non-preemptive Priority Scheduling, with aging; where priority is 
decremented by 1 if the process remains in the ready queue for 5 time units.
```

For this assignment, you may use any programming language of your choosing.

| Process | Arrival Time | Burst Time | Comes back after | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 0 | 10 | 2 | 3 |
| P2 | 1 | 8 | 4 | 2 |
| P3 | 3 | 14 | 6 | 3 |
| P4 | 4 | 7 | 8 | 1 |
| P5 | 6 | 5 | 3 | 0 |
| P5 | 7 | 4 | 6 | 1 |
| P7 | 8 | 6 | 9 | 2 |

Hint: You should create a process that initially creates the 7 processes, and continuously updates the status of the processes, and another process that schedules those processes, and plots the results ,

my question is how do i use this come back time ?

the process must be finished why would it return to the ready queue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> my question is how do i use this come back time ? the process must be finished why would it return to the ready queue?

The problem statement says that:

> > Once each process is done processing its “Burst Time”, it goes to the waiting queue, then “Comes back” to the ready queue after the time shown.

Burst Time is the maximum duration allowed at a single go at a CPU (actually running on a CPU) for that process.  You might use the term time slot.  When a Process is allowed to run, the Burst Time timer/counter is reset to 0, and then incremented as the clock ticks, and if the Burst Time is met, then the Process is definitely not completed, and it had to be interrupted/stopped/suspended due to the Burst Time limit, rather than being finished.

(System timers/counters might run downwards, decremented from Burst Time down to 0 rather than incremented from 0 up to Burst Time.)

Since, by definition, a Process that reaches its Burst Time has not completed (still needs more CPU time), it is necessary to give it another chance at running, which is done by first waiting some duration, the Comes Back After, and then making it ready to run again, i.e. runnable.  When in the waiting period, it is ineligible to run, so will not be run (perhaps unless the ready queue is empty).  Once the wait duration has been reached, it becomes runnable again, and so is placed onto the ready queue and now competes with the other ready processes for some next cpu time slot.  (The wait duration ensures some manner of fairness, and can be 0 in some scenario, meaning there is no wait requirement before being ready to run again.)

On the other hand, when a process finishes, i.e. runs to successful completion finishing all its work, it will inform the system before the Burst Time limit is reached, i.e. still within its Burst Time.  It will be stopped immediately and removed from queues.

> You are required to simulate the CPU schedule for a period of 200 time units.

I don't see anything in this problem statement that says there is an amount of time for how long a process runs to completion, i.e. when it stops, so I think you are supposed to just run them all as if they never stop, for the 200 time units.

When a process stops, it will be in the middle of a time unit, possibly leaving fractional time units available for other processes.  You won't have to concern with that as the processes never finish in your scenario.